# How can I use inheritance in Unity effectively?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inheritance

I have basic understanding of inheritance but since every script I want as a component on a game object has to inherit from MonoBehaviour things get tricky.

Let's say I want to have a base class called Character and I want Player and Enemy to derive from Character. How am I suppose to add Player and Enemy script to Player and Enemy objects without getting an error?

I also tried to create empty game object and add CharacterStats to it then populate this class with different character objects with different stats. Guess what, you can't use new keyword to create objects if the script derives from Monobehaviour.

Is there some tutorials about this topic to make it more clear?

Comment: Generally speaking you want to avoid inheritance in Unity. Each script should be as self-contained as possible, preferring composition over inheritance

Comment: Inheritance in Unity is fine to do, and makes life simpler when done correctly.  If done incorrectly, it can cause some serious headaches.  As @UnholySheep mentions, Unity is aimed more toward composition (components on objects).  Don't let this discourage you from using inheritance though.  There are plenty of situations where inheritance just makes sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably the thing to understand is that `MonoBehaviour` itself inherits `Component` - A MonoBehaviour IS a Component.

When you look at it as if Components are a part of a thing, it makes at least some sense that you can't just `new` a Component - could I make a `new Arm`? If I did, where would it got? But I could make a `new Body body` and then do`body.AddComponent<Arm>`, right? Because then it's clear what happens to the Arm - it gets *attached to the body*.

Similarly you can't just `new` a Component because they're supposed to be a *part* of a GameObject. What you *can* do is to make a new GameObject and `.AddComponent<>()` to that object. Again, now it's clear *where* that Component is going.

I generally agree with [UnholySheep's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72047382/how-can-i-use-inheritance-in-unity-effectively#comment127304343_72047382) that you should prefer composition over inheritance because this generally makes your code more modular. That said, I definitely do also use inheritance.

The question you should be asking yourself when you're outlining your class is, "Is this new class a KIND of _____ or does this new class HAVE a _____." And it's easy I guess to say a Player is a Character and an Enemy is a Character, but do you *need* to subclass? Or would a Player just be a Character that also has a PlayerController? Maybe you could have an interface like `IPlayerController` and have a `LocalPlayerController` for the user and an `AIPlayerController` for the enemies? Lots of ways to problem-solve with programming.

Or maybe all Characters have a PlayerController and just the `.activeControl` bit is false for non-player characters. Then you could do things like ghost/spectate NPCs, etc.

But to your question specifically:

> Let's say I want to have a base class called Character and I want Player and Enemy to derive from Character. How am I suppose to add Player and Enemy script to Player and Enemy objects without getting an error?

You would start with a `Character` script that inherits MonoBehaviour and implements any of the logic that is common to both classes:

```
public class Character : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Your common character logic
}
```

Then you would have subclasses inherit `Character`:

```
public class Player : Character
{
    // Your Player-specific logic here
}
```

and

```
public class Enemy : Character
{
    // Your Enemy-specific logic here
}
```

Then you either add the `Enemy` and `Player` scripts to a GameObject in the editor or you can do it programmatically by getting a reference to the target GameObject (by setting the reference in editor or by creating a new GameObject in a script) and then you call `targetGameObject.AddComponent<YourComponentToAdd>();`.

Answer (score 2):

Using inheritance well comes from planning and iterating. Perhaps your Character class doesn't work well as a class for your enemies. I tend to have the player in their own class (unless its multiplayer) with enemies using their own base class. Below is an example of some inheritance I use in a 2D game I'm working on.

Base Class:
**Enemy.cs**

```
public abstract class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
  public Vector2 flyInPos;
  public Vector2 startPos;

  public bool isFlyingIn;

  public float flyInDuration = 5000f;
  public float flyInTime = 0f;

  public abstract void Destroy();

  public abstract void DestroyWithoutScore();

  public abstract void Attack();

  public abstract void Attack2();

  public abstract void Attack3();

  public abstract void FlyOut();

  public virtual void FlyIn()
  {
    isFlyingIn = true;
  }
}
```

Every enemy needs to have these elements. You'll notice most of the methods in my base class are marked **abstract** so that each class that inherits can have a unique set of Attacks, and Flying patterns. One thing to notice is that the base class is inheriting from MonoBehaviour. Here is how I implemented inheritance in one of my enemies. Sorry its still a WIP.

Inherited Class:
**ShootingDrone.cs**

```
public class ShootingDrone : Enemy
{
  public GameObject projectileSpawner;
  public GameObject projectile;

  public void Start()
  {
    startPos = transform.position;
    Scheduler.Invoke(Attack, 5f, gameObject);
  }

  public void Update()
  {
    if(isFlyingIn)
    {
      transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPos, flyInPos, flyInTime / flyInDuration);
      flyInTime += Time.deltaTime;
    }
  }

  public override void Attack()
  {
    Shoot();
    Scheduler.Invoke(Shoot, 0.25f, gameObject);
    Scheduler.Invoke(Shoot, 0.5f, gameObject);
  }

  public override void Attack2()
  {
    Attack();
  }

  public override void Attack3()
  {
    Attack();
  }

  public void Shoot()
  {
    GameObject newProjectile = Instantiate(projectile, projectileSpawner.transform);
    newProjectile.transform.parent = null;
  }

  public override void FlyOut()
  {
    throw new System.NotImplementedException();
  }

  public override void DestroyWithoutScore()
  {
    throw new System.NotImplementedException();
  }

  public override void Destroy()
  {
    Destroy(gameObject);
  }
}
```

The base class of **Enemy** inherits from MonoBehaviour. So when **Shooting Drone** inherits from **Enemy** it also is inheriting from MonoBehaviour.

For your problem of trying to add a new MonoBehaviour. The reason for this is that a MonoBehavior HAS to be attached to something. Imagine a Rigidbody with no GameObject, it doesn't work. If you wanted to make a "new" CharacterStats the way you would do that is:

```
CharacterStats stats = gameObject.AddComponent<CharacterStats>();
```

If you don't want your CharacterStats as a component, then simply remove the MonoBehavior inheritance from the class and instantiate it as new CharacterStats.

There are a variety of tutorials that cover inheritance, but depending on how new you are to the subject I would start with the [Unity official inheritance tutorial](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/inheritance). I do think this tutorial is too brief but I also like [CircutStreams tutorial](https://circuitstream.com/blog/learn-c-for-unity-lesson-6-inheritance-and-interfaces/) since it also mentions implementing Interfaces which can be a better solution to inheritance in many cases.

Comment: I would use an interface for what you're describing, if you're only using the abstract class to define methods. Inheritance is useful for describing what a thing IS, interfaces are useful for describing what a thing DOES. If you want to have lots of enemies, consider making things like `Attack` an interface on its own, and then you could have `Enemy` be a concrete class. It can have a `public IAttack attack1;`, etc., and then you could do `public void Attack1() => attack1.Attack();`. You can make each attack a Component and have a library of attacks, etc. instead of a ton of subclasses.

Comment: With a library of attacks you can mix-and-match attacks to make new prefabs, or you could even make an "enemy builder" or similar that lets you or other users make characters dynamically. If you keep everything as concrete subclasses then you're stuck with whatever selection of classes you've made and you're really limited in your flexibility to implement new combinations.

Comment: @Chuck Very strong point, your suggestion is quite similar to what my studio did for our game. The scope of my solo project is tiny, so this works but I agree for larger projects where you want that flexibility there are much better implementations than what I have above.

Comment: Yeah totally understandable, just wanted to offer some constructive criticism :)